# Node.JS app not listening on assigned port

Tags: node.js

I have a Node.JS application that should be listening on port 4567 when it is started. Ideally, the port should be shown in the output of nmap and netstat, but for some reason, it is not.

Starting the app does not open the port. Nothing is being written to /var/log/syslog to tell me what's going on and nothing is in the apps log files either. I'm using Forever to start the app.

Any clues?

The config file for the app is shown below

```
{
"base_url": "http://mysity",
"port": "4567",
"use_port": true,
"secret": "settee",
"bind_address": "0.0.0.0",
"database": "redis",
"redis": {
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": "6379",
    "password": "secret",
    "database": "0"
},
"bcrypt_rounds": 12,
"upload_path": "uploads",
"relative_path": ""
}
```

Edit1: I'm using Forever to start the app > "forever start app.js"

Btw, I'm running the same app on a local install, and the port is open and I can connect to the application, but not on the production server.

Comment: Show some code how you start the server process, just a config is not enough I guess

Comment: Edited post to show the command used to start the app. Hope that's what you were looking for.

Comment: Are you running a reverse proxy like nginx?

Comment: Eventually, I  will be, but right now, no. The idea for the app is to use Nginx proxy_pass to access the site from a subdomain or subfolder of the main site. Right now, I'm just try to access the app by appending the port to the url of the main site. Will configuring Nginx proxy_pass stop the port from showing up in the outputs of nmap ans netstat?

Comment: Could you post the lines of code around "createServer()"? (should be in "app.js" or "server.js")

Comment: I can't see a startup command...

Comment: @Tobi, There's no command in the apps config.json file.

Comment: @Qualcuno, I've looked in app.js and other js files in the root of the apps installation and I can't find that function. It's not even in the "forever" script.

Comment: @user3294281 how did you create the node app? which framework?

Comment: @Qualcuno, I didn't create it myself, just using a new and popular forum app. See it at http://community.nodebb.org/

Comment: I think the framework is Express

Comment: Could be its only listening on local interface (127.0.0.1) try configuring it to the lan interface address.

Answer (score 0):

Try running a reverse proxy like Nginx. Basically what it does is it listens to browser ports (normally :80 but :443 for HTTPS) and it relays the requests from those ports to the port specified in the config file. (nginx.conf).

So your nginx.conf might look like:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass       http://127.0.0.1:4567;
        proxy_redirect   off;
        proxy_set_header Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy   true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am actually running that setup on a local install and it works as intended, and I can access it the app from a subfolder of the Nginx installation, even though I'm using a version of Nginx that does not support websockets properly. But even at that, the port for the app still shows up in the output of nmap and netstat. When I set up Nginx proxy-pass on the production server, just like I have on the local install, I get this error: " connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:4567/", host."

Comment: You don't need to append :4567 to the URL anymore if you are using Nginx (assuming proxy_pass is correctly set-up). Just enter `mysite.com` and your page should already load.

Comment: [Edited post] Removed space between : and 4567

Comment: Note that the main site is a WP site running on Nginx and php-fpm with  Varnish in front. Varnish is listening on 80, while Nginx is on 8080. For the Node app, I want to be able to access it form a subfolder or a subdomain. I can already do this from the local install and can see its port in the output of nmap. Please see the question pertaining to that at http://ur1.ca/gw2gn